# Почему после сборки exe-файла через Pyinstaller приложение не читает config.ini?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, config

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я сделал телеграм-бота через aiogram. Весь код для него лежит в одном файле - parser.py, также используется конфигурационный файл config.ini. Все файлы лежат в одной папке. Через интерпретатор Python всё прекрасно работает. Но если создать exe-файл через pyinstaller (pyinstaller —onefile parser.py), то вылетает такая ошибка, как на скриншоте. То есть, как я понял, почему-то не получается прочитать конфиг. Не подскажете, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Файл config.ini:

```
token = 1111111111111
id_channel = 1111111111
id_channel_stat = 111111111111111
id_user = 1111111111111111111
```

Участок кода в parser.py, где происходит взаимодействие с config.ini:

```
path = '/'.join((os.path.abspath(__file__).replace('\\', '/')).split('/')[:-1])
config.read(os.path.join(path, "config.ini"), encoding='utf-8')

token = config['Settings']['token']
id_channel = config['Settings']['id_channel']
id_channel_stat = config['Settings']['id_channel_stat']
id_user = config['Settings']['id_user']
```

Comment: Это происходит потому что в `exe` ваш `path` выглядит так: ```C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI118602```

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому что в `exe` ваш `path` выглядит так: `C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI118602`.

Происходит это из-за особенностей "компиляции" `python`. Всё дело в том, что фактически (и довольно грубо) ваш `exe` - это самораспаковывающийся архив, в котором содержится ваш код и интерпретатор `python`.
Чтобы узнать путь к `exe` используйте это:
`path = '/'.join(sys.executable.replace('\\', '/').split('/')[:-1])`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь всё заработало!